# Add searchbar in second section of uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

```
class SelectionBoxViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
var searchbar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchbar.delegate = self
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {   
    tableView.reloadData()
}  

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
 if(section == 1){
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchbar
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    view.addSubview(searchbar)
        searchbar.sizeToFit()
    return view
    }
    return nil
}

}
```

It crashed at `tableView.reloadData()` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. And i found that the problem is caused by adding searcher in a `UIView`.

So is there any solution to do this? i want to implement search bar in second section header instead of the first one.

Comment: Where is datasource for tableview are you setting it properly . Please have a look UIsearchbar tutorial in following link https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Comment: `tableHeaderView` and `sectionHeader` both are different.

Answer (score 1):

Configure `UISearchBar` in `viewDidLoad`.
After that do:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if(section == 1) {
       return searchBar
    } else {
       return nil
    }
```